# Reputation Requirement for Meta Questions is a Catch-22

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have a few questions I want to ask about WordPress--mostly I want to ask HOW I should organize and ask my set of questions. So it seems to me I should ask on WordPress Meta that.

But to ask on Meta requires a 15 reputation.

Can someone explain how I can get a reputation when I'm not sure even how to ask my questions?

Comment: Since when is it 15, if it is just 5 :)

Comment: Right, it's 5. I'm such a newbie I can't even post a meta-meta question correctly. ;)

Comment: Is there something specific missing from [how to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? you might also consider checking the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of other sites. The meta of wp has some [content](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+ask) as well.

Answer (score 6):

[(It's 5 rep, not 15)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)

The problem is, if you *didn't* require 5 rep, there would be more people abusing the privilege that people who want to use it legitimately like yourself!

Looking at other highly voted questions should normally give you *an idea* of how to post your own question - and people aren't usually that tough that if the question is organized badly, they'll vote to close (what reason could they possibly give?!) - at *the most*, they *might* downvote, but they would comment and tell you how to fix the post.

The only other way to get rep is to:

- post good answers (1 upvote)
- suggest *helpful* edits (2 edits)

OR... if your question is good (which it will be as long as you show any research if applicable), 1 upvote on a question!